# Ecto Repo.exists?() do something only when false

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am pretty new to Elixir/Ecto and unlike other languages, I find it kind of confusing on how control flows work
I want to just only do something when `Repo.exists?()` returns false. According to the docs, this returns a boolean. I tried

```
**/Orginal OP code**
alias App.MyModule

params.id
    |> MyModule.check_if_person_exist()
    |> Repo.exists?()
    |> if false do
      IO.puts("\n\nFALSEEE\n\n")
      MySchema
      |> MySchema.changeset(%{data: data})
      |> Repo.insert_or_update()


...
...
App.MyModule file

def check_if_person_exist(id) do
  from(s in Schema
   where id = ^id,
   select %{
     person: s.person
   }
 )
end
```

```
case do
  false ->
    //do stuff
```

But I get an error saying `no case clause matching true`

I just want to do something only if false and not check for true. Is that not possible to do with Ecto/Elixir?

```
//**MyQuery.Module**
def myqueryfunc(id) do
 query = from(s in Schema
   where id = ^id,
   select %{
     person: s.person
   }
 )
end
```

```
//**Some other file**

alias MyQuery.Module

query = Module.myqueryfunc(id)

case Repo.one(query) do
 false ->
  MySchema
  |> MySchema.changeset(%{data: data})
  |> Repo.insert_or_update()
```

Do I have to take into consideration `true`?

I only care if it is false.

If I do have to handle true, what can I do to do nothing when it is true?

Will this work

```
query
|>Repo.exists?()
|> false
|> if(do: //insert or update)
```

Comment: If you are interested in the opposite condition, instead of `if/2` you might be interested in [`unless/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#unless/2). You can pipe it directly like `query |> Repo.exists?() |> unless do .. end`. It is basically the same as `|> Kernel.!() |> if`

Answer (score 2):

If there is no matching clause, the code will raise `CaseClauseError`

```elixir
iex||1 ▸ case true do
...||1 ▸   false -> :ok
...||1 ▸ end

** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: true
```

---

Yes, you need to cover all the possible outcomes with [`case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2). OTOH, we have [`if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#if/2), which is more tolerant and silently returns `nil` if there is no `else:` clause.

```elixir
iex||2 ▸ false |> if(do: :ok)
nil
```

So you might either do `if/2` or handle all the clauses in the [`case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#case/2) expression as

```elixir
query
|> Repo.exists?()
|> case do
  false -> ...
  true -> :ok # or `nil` or whatever
end
```

Comment: sorry I am having trouble following your if example. So this will work with Repo.exists? and if
Repo.exists?()
|> false
|> if(do: //insert or update)

Also updated in op

Comment: can you check my op to see if the updated code at bottom is valid please?

Comment: No, it’s not. `false` in my example is the input to `if/2`, in yours it’s `Repo.exists?`. Just remove `|> false` from your chain. `false |> if(do: :ok)` is the same as `if false, do: ok`, as by pipe definition.

Comment: I think I tried this and I got an error stating `if/3` does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Functional languages have the concept of pure functions. A pure function **must always** return a value, there is no such thing as procedures in elixir.

Case statements must be exhaustive, in your case your `Repo.exists?/1` returns `true` and in your case statement you don't handle it.

You can solve this problem in several ways:

1. Refactor to `if` :

```elixir
if !Repo.exists?(query) do
  MySchema
  |> MySchema.changeset(%{data: data})
  |> Repo.insert_or_update()
end
```

This solution however is not the best one, since function will either return nil or your updated entry, instead I would do the following:

```elixir
case Repo.one(query) do
  nil -> 
    MySchema
    |> MySchema.changeset(%{data: data})
    |> Repo.insert_or_update()
  result -> result
end
```

In this way you guarantee that you will return a entry in both cases. This practice is applied a lot even in ecto internals.

Comment: I tried you second example but it is not going into the `nil` block

Comment: @hnhl please be more specific. The examples in this answer do perfectly work.

Comment: I updated op, can you check again please?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you shouldn't use a pipe operator like this

```
code
|> Repo.exists?()
|> if do
```

the above one is an Ambiguous pipe statement, you could see [elixir pipe operator](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/pipe_operator)

You could use `case` statement like below to do your control flow

```
params.id
|> MyModule.check_if_person_exist()
|> Repo.exists?()
|> case do
    true -> nil
    false -> 
         IO.puts("\n\nFALSEEE\n\n")
         MySchema
         |> MySchema.changeset(%{data: data})
         |> Repo.insert_or_update()
end
```

Comment: First of all, you should not state your [not necessarily correct] opinion as a must. `|> if do` is perfectly legit. Besides that, this answer adds nothing to already existing ones.